# How to rename a automatically generated swig class

Tags: java, c++, swig

I have a function which return a pointer of a self-defined class. When i tried to convert c++ to java by swig, it automatically generate a type of "SWIGTYPE_p_xxxx", how to rename this class?

my function is `Session* Interpreter::createSession(const ScheduleConfig& config)`, here Session is a class i defined, the funciton return a ptr which is not support in java.

after convert, swig will generate a type called "SWIGTYPE_p_MNN__Session", how to rename this to "Session_p" or anything else? (just for neat and clean, I don't need to access details through this pointer)

tried ask Chatgpt, and tried to read the docs. nothing work.
also tried `%rename(Session) SWIGTYPE_p_MNN__Session;`, not work.

Comment: you say it returns a unique_ptr, but the signature you show returns a raw pointer. Btw that you asked chatgpt and got nothing useful is rather irrelevant. On the other hand, if you did read the docs and there are details that you do not understand or that didnt work out for you then you should tell about the details

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Sorry. Chatgpt tell me to use %rename which is useless. I also read(search) docs roughly but not able to find which tool is relevant :(  About pointer, yes it's a raw, my fault.

Comment: Please put a minimal C++ class example in your question, then I can try to come up with something.